# Error uploading images using Slim framework

Tags: php, slim-3

I am trying to create an API endpoint using Slim that allows people upload images. I am however having issues as I keep getting this error message,

> "Argument 2 passed to moveUploadedFile() must be an instance of
>   UploadedFile, instance of Slim\Http\UploadedFile given"

This is what I am doing:

```
$directory = __DIR__.'/uploads';

function moveUploadedFile($directory,  UploadedFile $uploadedFile)
{
    $extension = pathinfo($uploadedFile->getClientFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // see http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php
    $basename = bin2hex(random_bytes(8));
    $filename = sprintf('%s.%0.8s', $basename, $extension);

    $uploadedFile->moveTo($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);

    return $filename;
}

$files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
$uploadedFile = $files['photo'];
if ($uploadedFile->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $filename = moveUploadedFile($directory, $uploadedFile);                    
}
```

Please how I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

The error tells you that PHP is looking for class `UploadedFile` in current namespace because you add typehint for it. Since there is no class named `UploadedFile` in your current namespace, hence the error.

Add `use` clause for example

```
use Slim\Http\UploadedFile;

...
function moveUploadedFile($directory,  UploadedFile $uploadedFile)
{
    ...
}
```

or typehint full class name

```
function moveUploadedFile($directory,  Slim\Http\UploadedFile $uploadedFile)
{
    ...
}
```